# Why does the following code is giving an answer that is very far from the analytic answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn Python and I came across the following question:

"A ball is dropped straight down from a cliff with height h. The position of the ball after a time t
can be expressed as:

y(t) = v0*t − (at^2)/2 + h

where a is the acceleration (in m/s^2) and v0 is the initial velocity of the ball (measured in m/s).
We wish to find for how long time t1 is takes the ball to pass a certain height h1. In other words,
we wish to find the value of t1 such that y(t1) = h1. The position of the ball is measured per delta_t
seconds.
Write a program which finds out how long time t1 it takes before the ball reaches height h1 by
using a while loop. Here, we let h = 10m, y1 = 5m, delta_t = 0.01 s, v0 = 0m/s and a = 9.81m/s^2."

I wrote the following code in Python. The problem is that I get a different answer from the one I am expecting when I solve the problem on paper (for y1 = 5m, t = 1.01s, and for y1 = 3.6m, t = 1.14s). I am not sure where is the issue exactly. Here is my code:

```
import math
import numpy as np

h = 10
y1 = float(input("Enter the height you want:"))
delta = 0.01
t = v_i = 0
a = 9.81

y = v_i * t - (a * pow(t, 2)/2) + h


while True:
    if y <= y1:
        print("The object will be at height",format(y, "0.3") ,y1, "around the time", format(t, ".3"), "s")
        break
    else:
        t += delta
        h = y
        v_i = v_i - a*t
        y = v_i * t - (a * pow(t, 2)/2) + h
```

Comment: The given formula uses `v0`, no matter what time you're calculating for.  But your code is instead using `v_i`, which is being updated at each time step.

Comment: @jasonharper v0 (or v_i) must update every time the time steps forward as it is affected by the acceleration. Also, Even if I eliminate the term (v_i * t), it still won't give the expected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to derive a time `t` for which the distance is the same that the user requires.

For this you attempted to make a loop which *guesses* the time `t`.

Mistakes were made.

Its more simple than you think:

```py
h = 10
y1 = float(input("Enter the height you want:"))
delta = 0.01
t = 0
a = 9.81

y = h   # y starts at the top of the cliff

while y > y1:
    t += delta   # time t is still guessed here
    y = h - (a * pow(t, 2)/2)  # Just recalculate y for the new time t

print(f"The object will be at height {y1} around the time {t}")
```

Note that your `v_i` can be assumed to be `0` at all times.

Comment: So basically, I don't have to update the position (h) every iteration? It's working well, but I don't understand why I should not update the position (h) every iteration.

Comment: The formula gives you the exact height for *any* given time `t`. It is not itself iterative at all. You plug in a given `t` and you receive the resulting `h`. However, what you are after is a time `t`, given a requested `h` from the user, which is the opposite way round, so you are in need of a loop which tries various values for `t` (starting from `0.0` and incrementing by `0.01`) to see which will give you the `h` that has been requested.